# how to find the count of cell value and no of last continuous by pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image: Data Frame 1]

[image: Data Frame 2]
[image: output]

Data frame 1 have 3 week code, and data frame 2 have 4th week means last week code, now how to find the two columns , first is total no of cell count and no of last continuous cell

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to get more information about the week codes by turning them into columns with truth values.

```
>>> df1
  week1 week2 week3
0    bk    mm    xz
1    ck    ij    bk
2    ka    xz    zz
3    xz    dk    bv
4    ij    mn    ka
5    ik    ik    xy
6    bv    ka    xx
7    xy    xx    ck
8    mn    ck    ik

>>> df2
  week4
0    ka
1    bk
2    ck
3    xy
4    xz
5    zz
6    ik
7    xx
8    bv
```

Start by joining your two DataFrames to bring all the weeks data together.

```py
df = df1.join(df2)
```

Now gather all unique week codes and generate a list of codes for each week. We can then combine these in a new DataFrame.

```py
codes = np.unique(df)
weeks = df.T.apply(list, axis=1)

d = {c: [(c in w) for w in weeks] for c in codes}
newDf = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=weeks.index)
```

```
>>> newDf
          bk     bv    ck     dk     ij    ik    ka     mm     mn     xx     xy    xz     zz
week1   True   True  True  False   True  True  True  False   True  False   True  True  False
week2  False  False  True   True   True  True  True   True   True   True  False  True  False
week3   True   True  True  False  False  True  True  False  False   True   True  True   True
week4   True   True  True  False  False  True  True  False  False   True   True  True   True
```

Now we can get total cell count easily and number of continuous cells using a neat 'cumsum' trick.

```py
totals = newDf.sum()
continues = (newDf.cumsum() -
             newDf.cumsum().where(~newDf).ffill().fillna(0)).iloc[-1]
```

Finally you can fill in your total columns in DataFrame #2, using the above as lookup tables.

```py
df2['Total Number of cell'] = df2['week4'].apply(lambda code: totals[code])
df2['No. of time last continuous'] = df2['week4'].apply(
    lambda code: continues[code]).astype(int)
```

results in

```py
>>> df2
  week4  Total Number of cell  No. of time last continuous
0    ka                     4                            4
1    bk                     3                            2
2    ck                     4                            4
3    xy                     3                            2
4    xz                     4                            4
5    zz                     2                            2
6    ik                     4                            4
7    xx                     3                            3
8    bv                     3                            2
```

Comment: df2['No. of time last continuous'] not correct output

Comment: I edited my code to use the table you gave and got the right output after casting `df2['No. of time last continuous']` to `int`. Do make sure all your week columns (1 to 4) are in one DataFrame.